# Remmina troubles

Tags: linux, whonix, remmina

Installed remmina and now trying to run it with `sudo remmina`.
But getting this:

```
No protocol specified

** (remmina:9005): WARNING **: Could not open X display
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(remmina:9005): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Run it without `sudo` :-)